# Recycle Application Mod_Mono 2.8

Tags: asp.net, mono, apache, mod-mono, recycle

I have a CentOS 5.x server running Mono 2.8.1 and mod_mono 2.8 with apache2.

Every time I deploy a site from visual studio 2010 to my server by ftp, and navigate to the site, I get a 404 not found error page.

Sites in other subdomains (virtual hosts) are not affected.

Performing a restart of httpd using /etc/init.d/httpd restart fixes the problem, and I can view my ASP site again. Obviously restarting the entire httpd process is less than adequate.

My guess is that this is similar to application domains in IIS. Is there a way to 'recycle' and app domain in mod_mono? Can I set this to happen on deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do `/etc/init.d/httpd reload` to force Apache to re-read its files from /etc/apache without it having to restart.

Comment: This works. I will use an amalgamation of the 2 techniques to 'auto-reload' on upload.

Answer (score 1):

We have a process that attempts to download a hosted URL every minute, and if it returns 404, we kill -9 mod_mono.  That should be enough, you shouldn't need to touch Apache.

Comment: I get a response `bash: kill: mod_mono: arguments must be process or job IDs` when I try `kill -9 mod_mono`... Any ideas? Sounds like this could be a goer if it works...

Comment: You have to use ps to find the process id of mod_mono, and pass that value to kill.